# Merge 2 dfs, with the row if it is the only row that contains the word

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, merge

I have 2 pandas data frames:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['Sox','Sox','Jays','D', 'Jays'],
                   'val':[1,2,3,4,5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a b c', 'Sox Red', 'Blue Jays White Sox'],
                   'city':[f'city-{i}' for i in [1,2,3]],
                   'info': [5, 6, 7]})
```

```py
>>> df1
    keyword val
0   Sox     1
1   Sox     2
2   Jays    3
3   D       4
4   Jays    5

>>> df2
    name                 city       info
0   a b c                city-1     5
1   Sox Red              city-2     6
2   Blue Jays White Sox  city-3     7
```

For each row of `df1` the merge should be taking the exact element of `df1['keyword']` and see if it is present in each of the `df2['name']` elements (e.g. using `.str.contains`). Now there can be the following options:

- if it is present in exactly 1 row of `df2['name']`: match the current row of `df1` with this 1 row of `df2`.
- otherwise (if it is present in more than 1 or in 0 rows of `df2['name']`): don't match the current row of `df1` with anything - the values will be `NaN`.

The result should look like this:

```py
    keyword  val  name                 city    info
0   Sox      1    NaN                  NaN     NaN
1   Sox      2    NaN                  NaN     NaN
2   Jays     3    Blue Jays White Sox  city-3  7.0
3   D        4    NaN                  NaN     NaN
4   Jays     5    Blue Jays White Sox  city-3  7.0
```

Here in the column `"keyword"`:

- `"Sox"` matches multiples lines of `df2` (lines 1 and 2), so its merged with `NaN`s,
- `"D"` matches 0 lines of `df2`, so it's also merged with `NaN`s,
- `"Jays"` matches exactly 1 line in `df2` (line 2), so it's merged with this line.

How to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex and [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract the keywords, remove the duplicates with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), and finally [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['keyword']))
# 'Sox|Sox|Jays|D|Jays

key = (df2['name'].str.extractall(fr'\b({pattern})\b')[0]
      .droplevel('match')
      .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
      )

out = df1.merge(df2.assign(keyword=key),
                on='keyword', how='left')

print(out)
```

*NB. I'm assuming you want to match full words only, if not remove the word boundaries (`\b`).*

Output:

```
  keyword  val                 name    city  info
0     Sox    1                  NaN     NaN   NaN
1     Sox    2                  NaN     NaN   NaN
2    Jays    3  Blue Jays White Sox  city-3   7.0
3       D    4                  NaN     NaN   NaN
4    Jays    5  Blue Jays White Sox  city-3   7.0
```

Comment: and if `key` has duplicate indices then to solve the `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` it is enough to add `.loc[key.index]` like this: `out = df1.merge(df2.loc[key.index].assign(keyword=key),`

Comment: @VladimirFokow you can also read my [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74936872/1), I had misunderstood the order of the merge and was filtering on index ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a combination of `.apply()` and `.str.contains()` to find the rows in `df2` that match the rows in `df1`. Then, we can use `.merge()` to merge the resulting data frames:

```py
def merge_dfs(row):
    keyword = row['keyword']
    df2_match = df2[df2['name'].str.contains(keyword)]
    return df2_match.iloc[0] if len(df2_match) == 1 else pd.Series(dtype='float64')
result = df1.apply(merge_dfs, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
result = df1.merge(result, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

This should give the desired result:

```py
>>> result
    keyword val city    info    name
0   Sox     1   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   Sox     2   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   Jays    3   city-3  7.0     Blue Jays White Sox
3   D       4   NaN     NaN     NaN
4   Jays    5   city-3  7.0     Blue Jays White Sox
```